# What's the difference between `-C` and `-c` in `tr` command?

Tags: command-line, tr

Today I learnt a bit about `tr` command.

But I was stuck at understanding the difference between `-c` and `-C`.

On the manual, it said:

```
 -C      Complement the set of characters in string1, that is ``-C ab'' includes every character except for `a' and `b'.

 -c      Same as -C but complement the set of values in string1.
```

I'm not quite understand what does `set of values in string1` of `-c` option mean.
I thought it may treat string 1 `"ab"` as a whole and will escape single `a` and `b`.
So I did an experiment:

```
⇒  echo "ab_a_b" | tr -C 'ba' 'c'
abcacbc%                                                                                                                                                                             
⇒  echo "ab_a_b" | tr -c 'ba' 'c'
abcacbc%
```

Things didn't match my expectation!
So, what's the difference between `-C` and `-c` in `tr` command?

---

Software Version: BSD 2004 on OSX10.10

Comment: See this discussion: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/11059/focus=11101

Comment: Does this answer your question? [understanding the difference between "-C" and "-c" in tr(1) utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74855/understanding-the-difference-between-c-and-c-in-tr1-utility)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The POSIX manual says this:

> - If the -C option is specified, the complements of the characters specified by string1 (the set of all characters in the current character set, as defined by the current setting of LC_CTYPE, except for those actually specified in the string1 operand) shall be placed in the array in ascending collation sequence, as defined by the current setting of LC_COLLATE.
> - If the -c option is specified, the complement of the values specified by string1 shall be placed in the array in ascending order by binary value.

and contains the following note

> The ISO POSIX-2:1993 standard had a -c option that behaved similarly to the -C option, but did not supply functionality equivalent to the -c option specified in POSIX.1-2008. This meant that historical practice of being able to specify tr -cd\000-\177 (which would delete all bytes with the top bit set) would have no effect because, in the C locale, bytes with the values octal 200 to octal 377 are not characters.

From this it appears that the `-c` option let you specify numeric values representing ASCII character instead of using the characters themselves.

Comment: Auh, I guess because mine was the 2004 BSD version on OSX.

Comment: But still curious about what does the `set of values` mean in this early version.

Comment: @Zen see my edit

Comment: No, they're not the same on BSDs. See [there](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/11059/focus=11101) for details.

Answer (score 3):

this question is actually then about BSD tr, not gnu tr.

BSD tr man:

```
 -C      Complement the set of characters in string1, that is ``-C ab''
         includes every character except for `a' and `b'.

 -c      Same as -C but complement the set of values in string1.

FreeBSD 8.2                    October 13, 2006
```

GNU tr man:

```
   -c, -C, --complement
          use the complement of SET1
```

OSX built in tools will I believe be the BSD versions.

[fixed typo, sed/tr]